# How to achieve dependency injection with a custom UIViewController subclass initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, dependency-injection

I have a UITabBarController subclass which depends on a MyAppsData object. I am trying to inject MyAppsData into the UITabBarController subclass by adding a new designated initializer, like that:

```
- (instancetype)initWithMyAppsData:(MyAppsData *)data {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        self.appData = data;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Setup stuff based on self.appData
}
```

However when I try to setup stuff based on self.appData inside viewDidLoad, self.appData is nil. Turns out: The call to initWithNibName already calls loadView before the initializer could set the appData property. Apparently initWithNibName does that when you initialize a view controller without a nib. I generally seems to be the safer bet to setup view controller properties in viewDidLoad.

So here's my question: What is the best way to do dependency injection with UIViewControllers while instantiating them programmatically?

Comment: I suspect that you either need to handle the entire initialisation process yourself by calling `[super init]` rather than initWithNibName or you can access your property in `viewWillAppear` or you could implement your class in Swift

Comment: Hi Stefan, can you tell how you are initiating the uiviewcontroller subclass? It seems that initWithNibName can't result in calling viewDidLoad as there is no nib name mentioned.

Comment: @AvinashB Well this is quite old, but: If you pass nil for nibName, UIViewController can find a nib file automatically (see nibName property documentation) or you can create your view programmatically. Either way, viewDidLoad will be called.